# GET call responding with status 200 and then immediately giving 500.

Tags: java

so i been spending lot of time on this error:

little overview; basically made a simple get call that does this behavior:

```
Mar 27, 2017 2:43:44 PM org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter log
INFO: 1 * Server responded with a response on thread 1530388690@qtp-1144748369-0
1 < 200
1 < Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET POST, DELETE, PUT
1 < Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
1 < Allow: OPTIONS
1 < Content-Type: application/json

Mar 27, 2017 2:43:45 PM org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter log
INFO: 2 * Server responded with a response on thread 1530388690@qtp-1144748369-0
2 < 500
```

as you may see, it responds with a correct 200 but fails right after for some reason. after hours of debugging i realized if i am not mapping the collections that being many to many or one to many mappings, the response does fail..

the following is the example i am doing all my mappings:

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name="user_specializations",
joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="user_id"), 
inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="specialization_id")
)

private Collection<Specialization> specializationsList = new ArrayList<Specialization>();

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
private Set<Research> researchSet = new HashSet<Research>();
```

when ever i map these the response fails else wise it doesn’t so maybe its just cuz my response isn’t serialized but i even tried Gson and jackson annotations but nothing worked.
any ideas??

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/{email}/getUser")
public Response getUserByEmail (@PathParam("email") String email){
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
userInformation = new UserInformation();
UserDataPojo userData = userInformation.getPrimaryUserInfo(email);
return Response.ok()
.entity(userData)
.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET POST, DELETE, PUT")
.allow("OPTIONS").build();
}
```

Comment: have you received two 200 together?

Comment: not understanding your question. are you meaning to say that you are calling this method twice and the second time it fails?  And why are you doing `.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET POST, DELETE, PUT")`